# Make joomla blog link to inner pages(or blog roll post actual)

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

So i was told to create a blog for client in Joomla and, i have minimal knowledge of Joomla inner workings. I made the blog as seen here

http://www.assurancepower.com/about-us/blog.html

But the problem is that, the headers/titles for each story in that blog roll cant be clicked.
Im wondering is there a way i can make this happen? Essentially this page is a collection of the stories and i want to be able to click on a particular one (any of them) and be taken to its inner page/full version of the story.

Not exactly sure what im supposed to do/search for. Im not sure if joomla has a wordpress like functions.php or for example, is there somewhere i can instert a....maybe something like how wordpress does it with permalinks like so:

```
<?php permalink(); ?> //title link here to the actual story.
```

or something like

```
<?php bloginfo('url');?>// this relative link for WP.
```

Etc, **All** i want is to be able to have these titles in this story be active links to their full counterpart. Not sure what to look for/how to go about fixing this.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check in the menu item that titles linkable is enabled ?

> Menus -> (Your Menu) -> (Click on the menu item) -> Parameters (Component) -> Title Linkable

You can try this too if the above setting is ok:

http://www.2020media.com/content/view/240/38/

If none work then check if the template allows it, otherwise you'd have to override it or modify the template.

Comment: Hello Shaz, thanks for your response. I dont see the "edit menu item" not sure if im looking in the right place but on the admin panel, i went to the menus/menu manager and nothing. Also on the admin panels menu dropdown, i dont see "edit menu item" or "menu item" etc. The version is 1.5.26 and under that i see "legacy 1.0"

Comment: In the menu manager, edit that specific item within its menu and look to the right, search for 'Parameters (Component)'